# Accessing inside VLANs from DMZ interface on a Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco-asa

I have set up a test machine on my dmz2 interface.  I need to access the inside VLAN configured on the core L3 which has a route from ASA to core L3. 
Below is the basic configuration on the ASA :

For example, I need to access from 172.25.36.10 (source DMZ2) to 172.26.119.x (inside LAN).

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address <public ip> 255.255.255.224 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.26.72.2 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description ASA DMZ 1
 nameif DMZ1
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.25.43.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 description TEST_INT
 nameif DMZ2
 security-level 60
 ip address 172.25.36.1 255.255.255.0 
!
access-list Test_DMZ standard permit host 172.25.36.10 
access-list DMZ2_RemoteTest extended permit ip object-group obj_172.25.36.0_24 object-group TiVo_NT 

access-group DMZ2_RemoteTest in interface DMZ2
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 164.164.95.33 1
route inside 172.25.33.12 255.255.255.255 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.25.33.52 255.255.255.255 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.25.35.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.78.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.88.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.90.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.94.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.96.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.102.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.104.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.108.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.110.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.112.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.114.0 255.255.254.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.119.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.142.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.148.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.4 1
route inside 172.26.150.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.156.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.157.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.158.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.4 1
route inside 172.26.162.0 255.255.254.0 172.26.72.4 1
route inside 172.26.166.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.168.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.4 1
route inside 172.26.172.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.174.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 172.26.178.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 192.168.105.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.3 1
route inside 192.168.123.15 255.255.255.255 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 192.168.123.230 255.255.255.255 172.26.72.1 1
route inside 192.168.149.0 255.255.255.0 172.26.72.1 1
```

Comment: It may not be a good idea to allow your DMZ unfettered access to the rest of your LAN since devices in the DMZ are considered suspect. Why even have the DMZ? Just put those devices on your LAN.

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for your reply.  The machine is a terminal server hosted on the DMZ for remote access.  Users will login to the terminal server and will access their internal lan. I just wanted to allows few of the subnets on the inside lan from the terminal server.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, just add a new line to your existing ACL.  For something fairly open and insecure, you could try:

```
access-list DMZ2_RemoteTest ext permit ip host 172.25.36.10 172.26.119.0 255.255.255.0
```

Or for something more limited and secure, you could try:

```
access-list DMZ2_RemoteTest ext permit tcp host 172.25.36.10 172.26.119.0 255.255.255.0 eq 3389
```